# Determining Cross Domain Active Directory Group Membership

Tags: c++, active-directory, group-membership

I am currently working on a project where I need to query Active Directory to determine group membership of a user. I initially was locating the user and retrieving the memberOf attribute. The problem with this is that there is a domain and a child domain. The groups are universal groups so they can be used in both domains and they don't show up in the memberOf attribute. Unfortunately there doesn't seem to be much info around for Active Directory access with C++. Is there anyway to determine group membership in this case in C++?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using managed C++, you can use [UserPrincipal.GetAuthorizationGroups](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.userprincipal.getauthorizationgroups.aspx).

If you are not using managed C++, to solve this particular problem, you should bind to Global Catalog and do a LDAP search on the member attribute of the group object to find out which Universal Group containing the user.  You should limit your search by specifing the groupType, objectCategory and objectClass.

However, like I mentioned in another [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4569175/get-users-from-acctive-directory-group/4575613#4575613) , group enumeration in general is very hard to do it right.  If you just need to find out all the groups a user belongs to, your best bet is to use [S4USelf](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc188757.aspx)