# Listing Members of a Group

Tags: active-directory, active-directory-group

I see that this has been asked quite a few times but I think I'm taking a different approach to the problem.  I have an LDAP connection string that is working - it connects to a group.  Something like the following:

```
var myGrp = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://server.domain.com:389/CN=GroupName,OU=RAM,OU=Groups,DC=region,DC=company,DC=com");
            myGrp.Username = "username";
            myGrp.Password = "password";
```

Now, I can print myGrp.Name without any issues.  I would now like to list all members of this group, but I'm not sure where to begin.  Any pointers would be awesome.

Comment: See my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4569175/get-users-from-acctive-directory-group/4575613#4575613) in another post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried this and it worked perfectly:

```
foreach (object dn in myGrp.Properties["member"])
            {
                Console.WriteLine(dn);
            }
```